# how to pass a c++ variable inside a sql query

Tags: c++, mysql

```
MYSQL* conn;

conn = mysql_init(0);

conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "seat_alloc", 0, NULL, 0);


int college_name="abc";

int branch_name="def";

int rank=123;

int qstate4 = mysql_query(conn,("INSERT into allocated_seats (rank,college,branch) values (rank,'" + college_name + "','" + branch_name + "')"  ).c_str());
```

I want to pass integer variable and string variables inside the query. String variables are coming fine. But instead of rank column 0 is added to database. What is the right way to insert all these 3 variables in table.

Comment: Don't build your sql statements with string operations. Write your statements with placeholders, prepare them and bind the values. You tagged the question with C++ but you are using the C API. MySQL provides a C++ API with OOP. I recommend to use it instead.

Comment: Please do some research about *prepared statements* and *variable binding*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build your sql statements with string operations. Write your statements with placeholders, prepare them and bind the values.

```
#include <mysql.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main() {
  MYSQL* conn = mysql_init(0);

  conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "seat_alloc", 0, NULL, 0);

  std::string college_name = "abc";

  std::string branch_name = "def";

  int rank = 123;

  auto* stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);
  std::string query = "INSERT into allocated_seats (rank,college,branch) values (?, ?, ?)";
  mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query.c_str(), query.length());
  MYSQL_BIND bind[3];
  memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));
  bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
  bind[0].buffer = &rank;
  bind[0].is_null= 0;
  bind[0].length= 0;

  unsigned long str1_length = college_name.length();
  bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  bind[1].buffer = const_cast<char*>(college_name.c_str());
  bind[1].buffer_length = college_name.length();
  bind[1].is_null= 0;
  bind[1].length = &str1_length;

  unsigned long str2_length = branch_name.length();
  bind[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  bind[2].buffer = const_cast<char*>(branch_name.c_str());
  bind[2].buffer_length = branch_name.length();
  bind[2].is_null= 0;
  bind[2].length = &str2_length;

  mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind);

  mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);

  mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
}
```

Of course you should check all return values and add error handling.

Here you can find more about this topic: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @abhinav If it solved your problem you should mark this question.